# How to make UISwitch a BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, ios4, uiswitch

Forgive me if this is a simple question, but is a UISwitch a boolean variable?  If it is not, how can I make it BOOL?

Please allow me to explain why I'm having trouble.

I declared my variable **in my FlipsideViewController.**

```
UISwitch* mySwitch;     //switch used to turn label2 on/off
```

also creating an accessor

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;
```

*EDIT: and of course I synthesize it.*

**Then** in Interface Builder I connected `mySwitch` to a Switch I created on that view.

***NOW***, I have a method that I'm using which is this **in the MainViewController**:

```
- (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text :(BOOL)isOn {

    [nameLabel setText:text]; 
    if (isOn==YES)
    [onLabel setText:(@"ON")];
      else
       [onLabel setText:(@"OFF")]; }
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever I run the program, the label *always displays **"OFF"***.  Do you have any clue why?  I'm really helpless.

I would really appreciate any help on this, and again I apologize for being such a newbie. :)

***EDIT: This is how I'm calling the method...***

```
 [self.delegate updateLabels: myTextField.text : mySwitch.state];
```

So, I'm passing in the state of the `mySwitch` UISwitch.

Comment: What is calling `updateLabels::`?  (BTW, it's rather bizarre not to name the second parameter - I wouldn't have even thought it to be valid)

Comment: **MainViewController** is calling `updateLabels`, which is located in a protocol declared in my **FlipsideViewController**.  I know, it's weird.   ***EDIT, SEE IN MY MAIN PARAGRAPH***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to connect the UISwitch to an IBAction method that updates isOn, or read the state of the switch in your test.

Here's the latter: **UPDATE** Changed the code after you clarified the relationships between the view controllers.

```
- (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text isOn:(BOOL)isOn {
    [nameLabel setText:text]; 
    if (isOn == YES) {
       [onLabel setText:(@"ON")];
    } else {
       [onLabel setText:(@"OFF")]; 
    }
}
```

The call to updateLabels, which I'm hoping exists in FlipSideViewController, should look something like this: (I obviously don't know your variables names.)

```
[self.delegate updateLabels:self.myTextField.text isOn:self.mySwitch.on];
```

Comment: Hello!  Thanks for replying.  That gives me an error, unfortunately.  I get "`Request for member 'mySwitch' in something not a structure or union`".

Comment: Yes, updateLabels is a method in my **MainViewController**, while `mySwitch` is a UISwitch located in **FlipsideViewController**.

Comment: So you're calling updateLabels from some code on FlipsideViewController?

Comment: Yes I'm calling it in FlipsideViewController using `[self.delegate updateLabels: myTextField.text : mySwitch.state];`

Comment: Check out my updated code above. Note that I changed the signature of your updateLabels method to make the intent of the parameters clearer.

Comment: There's your problem. You want the `on` property, not `state`.

Comment: AH, that did the trick!  I deeply appreciate all you efforts to help me!  Thank you!

Comment: Also, it's worth to note the `IBAction` should be fired at `Value Changed` event, not `Touch up Inside`event like other `IBAction`s.